# projection from mosaic into tile using gdal

Tags: python, tiles, projection, gdal

I have an image mosaic and want to be able to process it in tile and then write the tile into the disk in *.tif format. My question is how can I copy any projection information from the mosaic into each tile but only change the origin (ie, the top-left corner coordinates) because that is the only change that occurs to projection information of the image mosaic? I use gdal in python.

Regards,
Mehdi